# How to use WITH Clause in BULK COLLECET inside plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to know how to use `WITH` Clause in `BULK COLLECT` inside PL/SQL block.

Presently I am able to get the data into collection variable as below.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    type row_data is table of varchar2(256) ;
    row_d row_data;
begin
    select some_column bulk collect into row_d from some_table;
    dbms_output.put_line(row_d(1));
end;
```

But I need to get the data from different tables. For this I am using with clause as mentioned below.

```
with diff_tab_data as
(
select some_column from some_table1;
union all
select some_column from some_table2;
union all
select some_column from some_table3;
union all
select some_column from some_table4;
union all
select some_column from some_table5;
);
select some_column from diff_tab_data;
```

How to use the above query with bulk collect . I have already tried the same as below but I am getting the error

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    type row_data is table of varchar2(256) ;
    row_d row_data;
begin
    with diff_tab_data as
    (
    select some_column from some_table1
    union all
    select some_column from some_table2
    union all
    select some_column from some_table3
    union all
    select some_column from some_table4
    union all
    select some_column from some_table5
    );
    select some_column into bulk collect row_d from diff_tab_data;
    dbms_output.put_line(row_d(1));
end;
```

Request you to help in this

Answer (score 0):

Example based on Scott's sample tables:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE row_data IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (256);
  3
  4     row_d  row_data;
  5  BEGIN
  6     WITH
  7        diff_tab_data (col)
  8        AS
  9           (SELECT dname FROM dept
 10            UNION ALL
 11            SELECT ename FROM emp
 12            UNION ALL
 13            SELECT loc FROM dept
 14            UNION ALL
 15            SELECT job FROM emp
 16            UNION ALL
 17            SELECT dummy FROM DUAL)
 18     SELECT col
 19       BULK COLLECT INTO row_d
 20       FROM diff_tab_data;
 21
 22     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (row_d (1));
 23  END;
 24  /
ACCOUNTING

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

As you can see, each `select` in `with` factoring clause does **not** end with a statement terminator. The rest of it, you did mostly OK (missing `bulk collect`).

Comment: Thanks. It's my silly mistake. It's working.